# Incoming calls are rejected because there is no 's' extension

Tags: asterisk

I've have configured VOIP provider and voip device.

Sip config as follows

```
sip.conf
[operator]
canreinvite=no
context=from-operator
host=operator_ip
secret=operator_secret
type=peer
qualify=yes
port=5060
defaultuser=operator_number
fromuser=operator_number
fromhost=operator_ip
fromdomain=operator_ip
dtmfmode=rfc2833
authuser=operator_number@operator_ip
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=yes
insecure=invite

[office1]
type=friend
secret=my_secret
host=dynamic
qualify=yes
directmedia=no
context=from-office
nat=force_rport,comedia
```

```
extensions.conf
[from-operator]

; call office1
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/office1)
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()
```

When I call my operator number, it should redirect to office1.

However I'm getting following error.

```
Call from 'OPERATOR_NUMBER' (X.55.178.68:5060) to extension 's' rejected because extension not found in context 'from-operator'.
```

I don't know where that `'s'` is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

s is "empty extension" or "start extension", see [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Special+Dialplan+Extensions)

That mean asterisk not able determine DST on incoming call.
Usually, that is call to **sip:ip_here:5060**

S will not match _X. pattern(which is DIGIT+something, at least two positions).

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching

You can catch s in dialplan(write rule for s) or you can try find DST from sip headers(see sip debug to determine if that possible).

Comment: Thanks. I changed to 
`exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/office2)``exten => s,n,Hangup()` It's working.